# Copy HSSFCellStyle to XSSFCellStyle in NPOI

Tags: c#, .net, excel, npoi, xssf

My input file is .xls from where I have to read data, manipulate and write back to .xlsx file along with the styles.

So, using **NPOI HSSF** to read from .xls and **NPOI XSSF** to generate the .xlsx file.
I am done with the data. But I have to copy the cell formats from the .xls and apply to the output file.

When I write `outputheaderStyle.CloneStyleFrom(inputheaderStyle);` an exception occurs as inputheaderStyle is of type HSSFCellStyle and outputheaderStyle is of type XSSFCellStyle

> Can only clone from one XSSFCellStyle to another, not between
>   HSSFCellStyle and XSSFCellStyle

```
outputheaderStyle.CloneStyleFrom((XSSFCellStyle)inputheaderStyle);
```

throws exception

> Unable to cast object of type 'NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFCellStyle' to
>   type 'NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFCellStyle'

Is there any other way to copy the style?

Comment: i not 100% sure, but I think whith NPOI you can hanlde xls files and xslx files. Looks like you got the two of the mixed up

Comment: I know I mixed up both. But, its customer requirement that input is always in .xls format and output must be in .xlsx format with all the style

Comment: oke, I read the question wrong. customers and there requirements :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the cell style of .xls file is HSSFCellStyle and for .xlsx file it is XSSFCellStyle. Currently there is no direct way to convert the HSSFCellStyle to XSSFCellStyle in NPOI.

I managed my program by copying one by one style individually.

```
_xssfStyle .BorderLeft = _hssfStyle .BorderLeft;
_xssfStyle .BorderRight = _hssfStyle .BorderRight;
_xssfStyle .BorderTop = _hssfStyle .BorderTop;
_xssfStyle .BorderBottom = _hssfStyle .BorderBottom;
_xssfStyle .FillForegroundColor = NPOI.HSSF.Util.HSSFColor.Grey25Percent.Index;
_xssfStyle .FillPattern = NPOI.SS.UserModel.FillPattern.SolidForeground;
_xssfStyle .WrapText = _hssfStyle .WrapText;
_xssfStyle .VerticalAlignment = _hssfStyle .VerticalAlignment;
```